# API gateway on localstack

Tags: aws-api-gateway, localstack

I was able to setup localstack (https://github.com/atlassian/localstack) and also create normal AG function in it (using create-rest-api... command).

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4567/ apigateway create-rest-api --name "MyFirstAPI" 


aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4567/ apigateway get-resources --rest-api-id 8A-Z04959201
```

However, I couldnt find a way to create an APIGateway in localstack and how do I redirect it to my project to call the API function.

I am looking for a solution without Lambda. I have some article where its being done using Lambda

Comment: localstack has moved a while ago and been updated with many additional features implemented. I don't think you'll find (or want) support for the older Atlassian-maintained solution. https://github.com/localstack/localstack